# It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to instantiate a class at runtime using

```
_syncHelper = (ISyncHelper) Activator.CreateInstance("SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation", "SyncHelper");


A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 

'SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase,    
Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)

at SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.DataHelper.get_SyncHelper() in e:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DataLayer\DataHelper.cs:line 35

at SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Context.SaveChanges() in e:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DataLayer\Context.cs:line 99

at SBD.Syrius.UI.MDIHelper.AttemptToSave(Context Db) in  e:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.UI\MDIHelper.cs:line 51

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = saturn\kirsten
LOG: DisplayName = SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation
(Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information 
and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/EShared/Syrius6/syrius_syrius/SBD.Syrius.UI/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : SBD.Syrius.DataLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file:    
E:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.UI\bin\Debug\SBD.Syrius.UI.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from    
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or    
location-based assembly bind).

LOG: Attempting download of new URL          file:///E:/EShared/Syrius6/syrius_syrius/SBD.Syrius.UI/bin/Debug/SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///E:/EShared/Syrius6/syrius_syrius/SBD.Syrius.UI/bin/Debug/SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation/SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/EShared/Syrius6/syrius_syrius/SBD.Syrius.UI/bin/Debug/SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation.EXE.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/EShared/Syrius6/syrius_syrius/SBD.Syrius.UI/bin/Debug/SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation/ SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation.EXE.
```

The error I receive contains a link to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx), but I cannot find an example of how to specify textual identity for the assembly.

I note that the full error indicates that it is looking int the wrong folder and also for a file with an uppercase .DLL . My file is creating with a lowercase .dll

Is there an example of how to provide a fully specified textual identity for an assembly? 
Should I be trying to change the case of the .dll extension?

If I actually copy the .dll to the UI\bin\debug folder then I get a different error

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SyncHelper' 
from assembly
```

'SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

```
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name,    
 Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)


at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)

 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,   Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
at SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.DataHelper.get_SyncHelper() in   

e:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DataLayer\DataHelper.cs:line 35
at SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Context.SaveChanges() in 

e:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.DataLayer\Context.cs:line 99

at SBD.Syrius.UI.MDIHelper.AttemptToSave(Context Db) in   
e:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.UI\MDIHelper.cs:line 51
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot three errors:

1. `Activator.CreateInstance` needs the complete name of type to load it
   it means that you must add namespace to the type name.
   Chances are you have more than one class with that name in different namespaces then how it could figure out which one be loaded.
2. You want to create an instance of an Interface which is impossible.
   `ISyncHelper` is an interface and you can not say:
   `var variable = new ISynchHelper()`

   It will cause compilation error, cause interfaces are just empty bodies and does not contain single line of implementation.
   So evertime that you use reflection to do smething, be careful, cause the compiler can not help you and if something is supposed to go wrong, you'll face it in runtime, not in compile time.
3. Last error is due to that there is no reference to Synchronization project in UI which means that it will not copied to Bin folder of UI project.

   You can do that by adding the Synchronization project to UI or just add a copy command to Synchronization project to be copied after build.

Good Luck :-)